# Как динамически убрать сообщение об ошибке при очишении поля ввода пользователем

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Всем привет! Использую Java и Primefaces. Отображаю ошибки при нажатии на кноаку Save - все работает. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - надо на лету убрать сообщение об ошибке если пользователь очистил поле ввода 
написал такой код

```
    <div class="item">
     <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="#{msgs['customerForm.firstName']}"/>
    <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{customerBean.customer.firstName}"
    requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.mandatory']}" required="true"
    validatorMessage = "#{msgs['Error.firstName.wrongFormat']}">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="container" event="keyup" immediate="true"/>
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*)?$"/>
   </p:inputText>
   <p:message id="m_firstName" for="firstName" display="text"/>
   <p:outputPanel id="container">
   <p:message id="m_zeroField" for="firstName" display="text" rendered="#{customerBean.customer.firstName.isEmpty()}"/>
   </p:outputPanel>
   </div>
```

но он не срабатывает, подскажите как
очищать сообщения об ошибке на лету если пользователь очистил поле

вот код кнопки сейв

```
<div class="commandButtons-1">
<p:commandButton value="#{msgs['customerForm.save']}" icon="ui-icon-check"
  onclick="customerFormSpaceTrimmer()"
  update="createEditCustomerForm" action="#{customerBean.saveCustomer}"/>

<p:commandButton value="#{msgs['customerForm.cancel']}" immediate="true"
   action="#{customerBean.backToSearch}"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите `p:message id="m_firstName"` и `p:message id="m_zeroField"`, вместо них сделайте `<p:messages id="msgs" for="firstName"/>`. В `f:ajax` укажите `render="msgs"`.

```
    <div class="item">
        <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="#{msgs['customerForm.firstName']}"/>
        <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{customerBean.customer.firstName}"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.mandatory']}" required="true"
                     validatorMessage = "#{msgs['Error.firstName.wrongFormat']}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="msgs"/>
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*)?$"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <p:messages id="msgs" for="firstName"/>
    </div>
```

Примечание 1: пример кода в вопросе не полный, Вы упоминаете кнопку Save, которой нет.

Примечание 2: Ваш эксперимент с `rendered="#{customerBean.customer.firstName.isEmpty()}"` не работает потому, что для обработки атрибута `rendered` требуется обновлять контейнер, в котором содержится элемент, а не сам элемент. Примерно так:

```
...
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="container"/>
...
        <p:outputPanel id="container">
            <p:message id="m_zeroField" for="firstName" display="text" rendered="#{customerBean.customer.firstName.isEmpty()}"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
```

**Обновление 1**: весь код страницы так и не приведён. Вот абстрактный пример страницы, решающей Вашу проблему:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
<h:head/>
<h:form>
    <div class="item">
        <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="Имя"/>
        <p:inputText id="firstName"
                     requiredMessage="Обязательно" required="true"
                     validatorMessage="Неверный формат">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="msgs"/>
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*)?$"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <p:messages id="msgs" for="firstName"/>
    </div>
</h:form>
</f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

Создайте файл с приведённым содержимым (один-в-один) и проверьте работоспособность. Далее постепенно переносите свою функциональность в этот файл до тех пор, пока не перестанет работать.

Comment: @bobzerСпасибо за быстрый отклик! Если я удаляю  p:message id="m_zeroField" - происходит вся валидация на лету. А мне необходимо что бы на лету только пропадало сообщение об ошибке если пользователь очистил поле

Comment: учел ваши требования - сейчас код в таком формате

Comment: я обновил данные вопроса -но все равно не работает(

Comment: Спасибо!  <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="msgs"/> - но ведь тогда будут проверяться все ошибки на лету? или я ошибаюсь? в таком стиле был мой исходник( он работает  - но выводит все ошибки на лету. Мне сейчас изменили спеку и надо что бы сообщения не проверялись на лету а только пропадали если пользователь очистил поле. Я уже два дня не могу придумать способ - в любом случае спасибо большое за ответы.

Comment: stackoverflow - ресурс, на котором на конкретные вопросы дают конкретные ответы. Если вопрос значительно изменился, следует задать его заново с новыми вводными данными, а не изменять постоянно исходный вариант.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682957/Как-мне-динамически-очистить-сообщение-валидатора-об-ошибке